# How to center div's that are inline-block'd

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make it so that these 4 div's are side by side but centered using margin: auto;

Here is it WITHOUT inline-block;

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d45Fb/)

HTML:

```
    <section class="stats">
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.stats {
    padding: 15px;
}

.box1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
```

Here it is WITH inline-block; (for some reason not centering with margin)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug2YZ/1/)

HTML:

```
    <section class="stats">
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <h5>Online Users</h5>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
    .stats {
    padding: 15px;
}

.box1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `text-align: center;` so the modified css would look like this:

```
.stats {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ug2YZ/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are your serious... Why does this work? Its not aligning any text, why doesnt margin auto do this? It worked though!

Comment: I did notice however, instead of the just background becoming larger, the div's themselves start to expand past the max-width.

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align:center;` to `.box1`

ie

```
.box1 {
margin: auto;
width: 20%;
background-color: #b0e0e6;
text-align:center;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To center text, you just need to use style "text-align:center" for box1 class. see code below

```
.box1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    text-align:center;
}
```